# WCF transaction over internet on production environment questions

Tags: wcf, transactions

Questions:

1. Why information on this subject are so poor?
2. Nobody uses WCF transaction services?
3. In this production environment is only allowed to use the ports 80 and 443,  WCF tranaction technology uses other ports?
4. This technology is interoperable in any way? Client Java server .NET C#?
5. I am using WCF transaction to ensure complete communication between the client and the service. There is another way to ensure this without using WCF Transaction?

I appreciate any help and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why information on this subject are so poor?

Because no-one in their right minds wants to do transactional service calls over port 80 on the public web unless there is no other option (including suicide).

> Nobody uses WCF transaction services?

See answer to the previous question.

> In this production environment is only allowed to use the ports 80 and
>   443, WCF transaction technology uses other ports?

No, WCF transactions are an implementation of [WS-Atomic Transaction](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-tx/wsat/2006/06), which uses port public ports. This was originally part of the SOAP 1.2 standard.

> This technology is interoperable in any way? Client Java server .NET C#?

In theory yes because it's based on a standard which, as long as it's implemented correctly, should be interoperable with any other correct implementation. However, in practice, standards are almost impossible to implement uniformly and so I would seriously doubt that .net and java implementations would just work with each other (they're rarely able to interop over SOAP 1.1 even).

> I am using WCF transaction to ensure complete communication between
>   the client and the service. There is another way to ensure this
>   without using WCF Transaction?

It depends on what you mean by *complete communication*. Complete meaning 100% ACID? That doesn't exist. What if the world blows up?

So 99.99% ACID? This level of *completeness* (1 failure per 10,000 calls) can be achieved without using any transactions at all. This is the normal operating range I would expect to see from a well-designed service-consumer interaction.

If you require a higher completeness rating you could have the service expose a recovery or rollback operation, so the consumer can take the appropriate action and rollback any calls made previously to a failed call. Such an approach is known as a [compensation pattern](http://soapatterns.org/design_patterns/compensating_service_transaction).